# UIAppearence Support for IOS 6 - unexpected results

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiappearance

Below code is perfectly working fine iOS 5, but not on iOS 6 or above.
What I want that for Email composer sheet the navigationBar image will be different then other UINavigationBar classes. I can't understand that debug pointer is responding the appearance method but on device it shows  navigationBar image as "bgNavigationBar.png"; expected is "bgNavigationBar_2.png".

Please guide me.......

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    UIImage *logoImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:logoImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage *ImagePlain = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar_2.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:ImagePlain forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: iOS 6 bug. Open Radar - http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=2984402

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This thing is not working in ios6.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMessageComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar_2.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Just you need to set this property in your Mail Handler Class.

```
if (![[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
{
    UIView *backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)]autorelease];

    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar_2.png"]]];
    controller.topViewController.navigationItem.titleView = backgroundView ;
}
else
{
    UIImage *gradientImagePlain = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar_2.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImagePlain forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

and then reset another image for all other navigation controller's background image.

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self.parentController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *gradientImagePlain = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgNavigationBar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImagePlain forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Hope this will work for you.